# Ray Intersection doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, So I have been working on a minecraft like builder, the idea is to be able to be able to quickly build huge structures, without mining etc. It's for the learning experience.

So now I'm stuck at an annoying point...

If I destroy a block from one side. It works correctly.

[image]
[image]

But once I move the camera to the other side, it goes all wrong.

[image]
[image]

So basically I'm stuck at this point and have no idea how to fix it.

I calculate the ray:

```
Ray getRay(MouseState mouseState)
        {
            Viewport vp = mainController.engine.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport;

            Vector3 nearPoint = new Vector3(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y, 0);
            Vector3 farPoint = new Vector3(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y, 1);



            nearPoint = vp.Unproject(nearPoint, camera.getProjectionMatrix(), camera.getViewMatrix(), Matrix.Identity);
            farPoint = vp.Unproject(farPoint, camera.getProjectionMatrix(), camera.getViewMatrix(), Matrix.Identity);

            Vector3 direction = Vector3.Normalize(farPoint - nearPoint);

            return new Ray(nearPoint, direction);
        }
```

And then just brute-check it with all the models' bounding boxes:

```
for (int y = world.settings.regionHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--)
    {
          gotblock = false;
          for (int x = 0; x < world.settings.regionWidth; x++)
              for (int z = 0; z < world.settings.regionLenght; z++)
              {
                  f = ray.Intersects(block[x, y, z].boundingBox);
                  if (f != null)
                  {
                       if (f < lowestDistance && world.block[(int)position.X * world.settings.regionWidth + x, y, (int)position.Y * world.settings.regionLenght + z] != BlockTypes.none)
                           {
                               result = new intVector3((int)position.X * world.settings.regionWidth + x, y, (int)position.Y * world.settings.regionLenght + z);
                                    gotblock = true;
                           }
                  }
              }
         if (gotblock)
             break;
    }
```

If you need any more information, just tell. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that on check for lowest distance, the distance could have been counted by negative numbers in a ray. Therefore, I just needed to compare the absolute values of distance, instead of only positive ones.

Like so:

```
for (int y = world.settings.regionHeight - 1; y >= 0; y--)
                {
                    gotblock = false;
                    for (int x = 0; x < world.settings.regionWidth; x++)
                        for (int z = 0; z < world.settings.regionLenght; z++)
                        {
                            f = ray.Intersects(block[x, y, z].boundingBox);

                            if (f != null)
                            {
                                f = Math.Abs((float)f);
                                if (f < lowestDistance && world.block[(int)position.X * world.settings.regionWidth + x, y, (int)position.Y * world.settings.regionLenght + z] != BlockTypes.none)
                                {
                                    lowestDistance = (float)f;
                                    result = new intVector3((int)position.X * world.settings.regionWidth + x, y, (int)position.Y * world.settings.regionLenght + z);
                                    gotblock = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    if (gotblock)
                        break;
                }
```